# WidgetKit / How to customise what to search for inside a widget intent configuration

Tags: ios, swift, widget

When we want to let an iOS Widget be customisable we need to add a custom intent definition.

With this, we can define different parameters inside the list (based on `INObjectCollection`)

Two important parameters are:

- `display`
- `subtitle`

With those two we can represent the list like this (from coinmarketcap):

[image: coinmarketcap widget configuration]

With this widget I can, for example, search for "Bitcoin" either way, by writing "Bitcoin" or by writing "BTC". How is it possible?

In a normal implementation, only the `display` parameter (e.g., Bitcoin) is used for filtering the result of the search.

What am I missing? How Can we configure the search bar to search for both values, `display` and `subtitle`?